# Java 8 PDFbox can't getText of pdf file

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, java-8, pdfbox

I am working on an application in Java 8 to process text from PDFs. I am using PDFbox version 2.0.12 in a Maven project. I am using the following method to extract text from a number of PDFs:

```
for(File file : fileEntry){
    PDDocument pdd = PDDocument.load(file);
    PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    String text = stripper.getText(pdd);
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

However, on this particular file:

http://www.o-cha.net/english/cup/pdf/29.pdf

I'm getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: TTF fonts do not have a CFF table
at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.OpenTypeFont.getCFF(OpenTypeFont.java:56)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType0.<init>(PDCIDFontType0.java:136)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFontFactory.createDescendantFont(PDFontFactory.java:121)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font.<init>(PDType0Font.java:192)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFontFactory.createFont(PDFontFactory.java:83)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources.getFont(PDResources.java:146)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.SetFontAndSize.process(SetFontAndSize.java:60)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:848)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStreamOperators(PDFStreamEngine.java:503)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:477)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processPage(PDFStreamEngine.java:150)
at org.apache.pdfbox.text.LegacyPDFStreamEngine.processPage(LegacyPDFStreamEngine.java:139)
at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.processPage(PDFTextStripper.java:391)
at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.processPages(PDFTextStripper.java:319)
at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.writeText(PDFTextStripper.java:266)
at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.getText(PDFTextStripper.java:227)
```

I'm not sure, but I believe this is because the PDF is using some font which PDFbox is not familiar with. I'm not sure this is the case, because as far as I'm aware the `getText` method of the PDFTextStripper class should ignore all styling. The documentation states:

> This class will take a pdf document and strip out all of the text and ignore the formatting and such.

If this is the case, why am I getting this exception?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I try your code and works fine, check if you file is not corrupt.

Comment: Works fine for me when using the ExtractText command line utility of pdfbox-app. I do get three  warn messages like "Using fallback ArialUnicodeMS for CID-keyed font FutoMinA101-Bold" but these are harmless in this context. Please test with the command line utility too. And check if you have several different versions in your classpath.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue either, not with the current PDFBox snapshot and not with the release 2.0.12. Probably your download is corrupt, probably your runtime class path does contain a different PDFBox (or dependency) version

Comment: Always remember that in cases like these, you want to create a [mcve], not just "so others have something to test", but also to help yourself do a sanity check: does it actually go wrong in a new dir with just a Test.java with a single `main` method, importing just the PDF package, compiled with just `javac`? If so, awesome, that's debuggable. If not: the problem is somewhere else.